# Can Google Sites API still be authorized?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I tested it in the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground and it looked like I could return info from the site, but when I set up the OAuth2 [code from Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2), I can't seem to do a UrlFetchApp request as I get
`the error returned code 403. Truncated server response: Not authorized to access this feed`
I am not sure if this is because it is not enabled in the API console, but I can't find it there or under Advanced Google Services.

This is the section of code I am falling down at:

```
var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
  Logger.log("initial xml has access "service.hasAccess());
    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken()
    };
    var MyAttachmentsURL = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/[DOMAIN]/[SITE NAME]?kind=attachment';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MyAttachmentsURL, headers);
  };
```

The script from Github worked for me and I authorized when the message came up.  This is what is in my scope tab:

> 7 OAuth Scopes required by the script:
>   https://sites.google.com/feeds
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Answer (score 0):

According to the Protocol Guide's "[Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#OAuth2Authorizing)" You must activate the Google Sites API in the API Console if you can see that option (Step 2).

---

The only other issue I can see is the [requiring to specify a version](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#Versioning) as `GData-Version: 1.4`.

So your code would change to something like this:

```
var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
  Logger.log("initial xml has access "service.hasAccess());
    var headers = {
      "GData-Version": "1.4",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken()
    };
    var MyAttachmentsURL = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/[DOMAIN]/[SITE NAME]?kind=attachment';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MyAttachmentsURL, headers);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for that Chris.  I had totally missed that part about the version being required.  Will give this a go tomorrow.  Hopefully that does the trick as the Sites API is not available in the console.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the scope is mentioned in the code, it doesn't need to be passed, so that wasn't the issue.  This was one of many variations I had been trying and I blame missing the `post method` on it being the wee hours.  This code works (for now).

```
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
  Logger.log("initial xml has access "+service.hasAccess());
    var headers = {
//      "GData-Version" : "1.4",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer "+service.token_.access_token
    };
    var params = {"headers": headers, 'method':'get', 'muteHttpExceptions':true};     
    var MyAttachmentsURL = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/[DOMAIN]/[SITE NAME]?kind=attachment';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MyAttachmentsURL, params);
    };
```

It appears that `"GData-Version" : "1.4"` is returned in the response header so is not needed in the request.  What is needed is the access token and although all the other API's seem to be able to make use of `.getAccessToken`, I had to amend this to `.token_.access_token` - this may be just for Google Sites.

I appreciate those who had a look at this and thank you Chris for responding.